# mySQL , Primary key to be used as foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables

```
| Car........| User........| UserCar......|
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| IdCar    Pk| IdUser   PK.| UserId   FK..|
| color......| name........| CarId    FK..|
```

I want to create a mySQL Stored procedure to which i am passing the IdCar(Car) that already exists and the name(User) of a user to be created.

The IdUser that has been generated later need to be added to the table UserCar.

If the tables can be acessed by multiple users what is the best way? triggers or LOCK table.

Comment: a stored procedure sounds like overkill. Wht are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already use a procedure, you can make the `INSERT INTO user`, get back the id and make your new `UserCar` record.

If you worry about two allocation of the same car, just use a `UNIQUE` constraint on `UserCar.CarId` and catch the error if you have a duplicate.